# replace multiple occurrences of any special character by one in python

Tags: python, regex, replace, special-characters

I have a string like:

```
string = "happy.....!!!"
```

And I want output like:

```
new_string = "happy.!"
```

I  know how to replace multiple occurrence of any special character. It can be done as follows:

```
line = re.sub('\.+', '.', line)
```

But I want to replace it for all special characters like ",./\, etc. 
One way is to write it for each special character.
But want to know if there is an easy way to write it for all special characters in one line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `\W` to match any non-word character:

```
line = re.sub(r'\W+', '.', line)
```

---

If you want to replace with same special character then use:

```
line = re.sub(r'(\W)(?=\1)', '', line)
```

Comment: NO, it will  replace all special char by ".". I want to replace multiple occurrence by that special character only.

Comment: Just edited my answer as before question edit it wasn't clear what your expected output is.

Comment: awesome. it is working. can you please explain it a bit.

Comment: Sure. `(\W)` wil match any non-word character and put it in a captured group #1. `(?=\1)` is a lookahead that makes sure there is atleast one more repetition of the same group. Replacement is empty string hence this removes all repetition of non-word characters.

Answer (score 9):

I think you mean this,

```
line = re.sub(r'(\W)\1+', r'\1', line)
```

https://regex101.com/r/eM5kV8/1